# Finding the indices of all points corresponding to a particular centroid using kmeans clustering

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, cluster-analysis, k-means

Here is a simple implementation of kmeans clustering (with the points in cluster labelled from 1 to 500):

```
from pylab import plot,show
from numpy import vstack,array
from numpy.random import rand
from scipy.cluster.vq import kmeans,vq

# data generation
data = vstack((rand(150,2) + array([.5,.5]),rand(150,2)))

# computing K-Means with K = 2 (2 clusters)
centroids,_ = kmeans(data,2)
# assign each sample to a cluster
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)

#ignore this, just labelling each point in cluster
for label, x, y in zip(labels, data[:, 0], data[:, 1]):
plt.annotate(
    label, 
   xy = (x, y), xytext = (-20, 20),
   textcoords = 'offset points', ha = 'right', va = 'bottom',
   bbox = dict(boxstyle = 'round,pad=0.5', fc = 'yellow', alpha = 0.5),
   arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', connectionstyle = 'arc3,rad=0'))

# some plotting using numpy's logical indexing
plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'ob',
     data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'or')
plot(centroids[:,0],centroids[:,1],'sg',markersize=8)
show()
```

I am trying to find the indices for all of the points within each cluster.[image: image without labels]

Comment: You've already assigned the points to clusters using `idx, _ = vq(data, centroids)`. Each element in `idx` is either a 0, corresponding to `centroids[0]`, or a 1 corresponding to `centroids[1]`. Isn't that what you're looking for?

Comment: My question is how do I get labels of item in centroid[0] and centroid[1].

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "labels". Maybe you want the indices of all of the elements in cluster 0, cluster 1 etc.? In that case you could use `in_0 = np.where(idx == 0)[0]`, `in_1 = np.where(idx == 1)[0]` etc.

Comment: Thank you for the answers. And  `where(idx ==1)`gives different indices each time I run the program. (I have more than 2 clusters in my scenario). Is that because the cluster[0] is different every-time?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20140816/1461210

Comment: Can you write the comments as an answer, so that I can accept it? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line:

```
idx,_ = vq(data,centroids)
```

you have already generated a vector containing the index of the nearest centroid for each point (row) in your `data` array.

It seems you want the row indices of all of the points that are nearest to centroid 0, centroid 1 etc. You can use [`np.nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) to find the indices where `idx == i` where `i` is the centroid you are interested in.

For example:

```
in_0 = np.nonzero(idx == 0)[0]
in_1 = np.nonzero(idx == 1)[0]
```

---

In the comments you also asked why the `idx` vector differs across runs. This is because if you pass an integer as the second parameter to `kmeans`, the centroid locations are randomly initialized ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20140816/1461210)).

Answer (score 1):

You already have that...

```
plot(data[idx==0,0],data[idx==0,1],'ob',
     data[idx==1,0],data[idx==1,1],'or')
```

Guess what `idx` does, and what `data[idx==0]` vs. `data[idx==1]` contain.

Comment: I am not looking for values (or co-ordinates) being plotted. I was looking for a way to get labels in cluster[1] and cluster[0]